# JMeter - If Controller not working for certain string contains condition?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-3.2, blazemeter

**Background:**
I have an API that returns a response like so:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "errorCode": null,
  "message": null,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 33,
      "snapshotId": 2,
      "ceId": 29,
      "month": "Feb",
      "corpRcvPayAmt": 100000,
      "wthRcvPayAmt": -90000
    },
    {
      "id": 31,
      "snapshotId": 2,
      "ceId": 29,
      "month": "Jan",
      "corpRcvPayAmt": 0,
      "wthRcvPayAmt": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The `data` node can vary from 0 size to 12 (empty to 1 per month). The only constant field for `data` is the `"month"` node. Other field values are changing.

**Goal:**
I want to do either a `PUT` or a `POST` request, depending on whether or not a specific month is already present in `data`.

For this, I'm capturing the entire `data` field into a variable using a **Regular Expression Extractor** like this:
[image]

With the sample response above, calling `${data}` will give me `{"id":33,"snapshotId":2,"ceId":29,"month":"Feb","corpRcvPayAmt":100000.00,"wthRcvPayAmt":-90000.00},{"id":31,"snapshotId":2,"ceId":29,"month":"Jan","corpRcvPayAmt":0.00,"wthRcvPayAmt":0.00}`

Now using this field, I just want to do a simple if condition like so: if `${data}` contains `${month}` do something (PUT request). I'm currently trying to do it like this:

[image]

**Problem:**

The condition `${__groovy("${data}".contains("Jan"))}` does not seem to work.
I've already tried doing the following:

change the condition to `${__groovy("${month}".contains("Jan"))}` just to see if the syntax is correct. This works just fine.

Add a debug sampler inside the if controller using the condition `${__groovy("${month}".contains("Jan"))}` to print `${data}`. This also prints the data as expected.[image]

I also tried using various js syntax for the if condition but so far groovy is the ongiving the best results.

With this I can confirm the following:

`${month}` and `${data}` are extracted and stored properly

groovy syntax for string contains is working properly

for some reason, the condition `${__groovy("${data}".contains("Jan"))}` is not working.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't reference [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in Groovy scripts as:

1. There could be a conflict with [GString Template](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html)
2. For [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) it causes compilation cache feature malfunction reducing the performance
3. Your variable might simply resolve into something which will cause Groovy script compilation failure and/or malfunction. You can check *jmeter.log* file for the actual error details.

So instead of using `${data}` go for `vars.get("data")` instead, `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance and this is the best way of getting a JMeter Variable value from the Groovy script.

The whole function should look like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('data').contains("Jan"),)}
```

Also be aware that it's better to use [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) for obtaining values from JSON responses.